# Grails 2.0: Use variable for image resource

Tags: grails, resources, image, gsp

I am passing a variable `logo` which contains the file name of an image file from my controller to the GSP and then I try to display the image like this:

```
<img src="${resource(dir:'images',file:"${logo}")}" alt="Logo" border="0" />
```

Even though the variable `logo` contains the correct value I get an `Unclosed GSP expression` error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing GroovyPageView
at org.grails.plugin.resource.DevModeSanityFilter.doFilter(DevModeSanityFilter.groovy:26) ~[plugin-classes/:na]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [na:1.6.0_26]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [na:1.6.0_26]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [na:1.6.0_26]
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException: Unclosed GSP expression
... 4 common frames omitted
```

Replacing `${logo}` with the file name works.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot

Jonas

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are trying to embeed Expresion Language inside Expresion Language.

Replace:

```
 <img src="${resource(dir:'images',file:"${logo}")}" alt="Logo" border="0" />
```

By

```
 <img src="${resource(dir:'images',file:logo)}" alt="Logo" border="0" />
```

Inside EL you can refer to variables directly

Answer (score 4):

Ernest is right that you shouldn't use a GString in this case. The actual error is that values aren't correctly quoted. 
You could also do

```
<img src='${resource(dir:"images",file:"${logo}")}' alt="Logo" border="0" />
```

(notice the single-quotes and double-quotes, they are properly closed)